# How to run a simple JUnit test in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit3

So here's my code:

```
package tests;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

class StatementTester extends TestCase { 
    public StatementTester (String name) { 
        super(name); 
    }

    protected void setUp() { 
    } 

    protected void tearDown() {  
    } 

    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("testing");
        assert(true);
    }

    public static Test suite() { 
        TestSuite suite= new TestSuite(); 
        suite.addTest(new StatementTester("test1")); 
        return suite; 
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        junit.textui.TestRunner.run (suite());
  } 
}
```

When I try to run this I get the following error message:

```
.E
Time: 0.001
There was 1 error:
1) test1(tests.StatementTester) at tests.StatementTester.main(StatementTester.java:30)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 0,  Errors: 1
```

I based my code on the example given in Chapter 4 of Martin Fowler's "Refactoring: Improving the design of existing code" (although I simplified it, but the base structure is the same). Also, I run eclipse 3.5.1 and use the JUnit 3 library (don't know how relevant it is, but anyway...)

Can you give me any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

First of all I'd like to say that there is a feature in eclipse that let you run the test without having to declare a main in your test class.

Here is a tutorial that will show you how to do it (with JUnit4) : 
http://www.vogella.de/articles/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 1):

With your file currently in the editor, <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>.  Or right click->Run As->JUnit Test.